# Find the domain of composition of two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $$f(x)= \frac{x}{x-9} \text{ and } g(x) = \frac{-6}{x+5} $$
>   Find the domain of $f \circ g.$

Please show the steps and substitution/algebra to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: Kinda lost honestly

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- What is the domain of $g$? call it $D$.
- What is the domain of $f$? there is a value of that is being excluded from the real value, call that number $c$.
- Solve for $y$ in $g(y)=c$, you have to make sure $y$ is not in the domain of $f \circ g$.
- The domain is $D \setminus \{ y\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f\circ g(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(x)-9}=\frac{\frac {-6}{x+5}}{\frac{-6}{x+5}-9}=\frac{\frac {-6}{x+5}}{\frac{-6-9x-45}{x+5}}=\frac 6{9x+51}=\frac2{3x+17}$

$\therefore x\not=\frac{-17}3, -5 $...

Actually,  I guess I did this "the long way".  We can't have $x=-5$ because it's not in the domain of $g$...

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you do one more? I posted it in a separate question.

Comment: Ok.  I'll look it up...