# Find the domain of composite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x) = \dfrac x {(x-3)}$; $g(x)= \dfrac {-7}{(x+7)}$

I found The domain of $(f \circ g)$ is $(- \infty, -28/3) \cup (-28/3 , -7) \cup (-7, \infty)$ which is correct.

Can someone please tell me the domain of $(g \circ f)(x)$ ? Show work if possible please.

Thanks!

Comment: i don't get it, you can solve for the domain for $f \circ g$ but not $g \circ f$? what is the technical difficulty that you face?

Comment: This is virtually identical to your other question from an hour ago [Find the domain of the composite function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627493/find-the-domain-of-the-composite-function), which was answered there. Voting to close as a duplicate. `Show work if possible please` That's yours to show, first. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yeah, the OP just wants us to do his homework. It should be already clear to the OP how to proceed as (s)he asked already about almost the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For $g\circ f$ I will try to do this the short way...

First, the domain of $f$ is:  $x\not=3$...

Second, the domain of $g$ is:  $x\not={-7}$.  Thus we cannot have $f(x)=-7$.  So we solve for $x$.
Get $\frac x{x-3}=-7 \implies x=-7x+21 \implies 8x=21 \implies x=\frac{21}8$.

Conclusion:   $x\not=\frac{21}8,3$

Comment: Thanks Chris! It was actually 3 instead of 7.

Comment: Good eye.  I will edit.

Comment: Thanks again ! Owe u one.

Answer (score 0):

Domain  of $(gof)(x)$ is $$ x\in (-\infty,21/8)\cup (21/8,3)\cup (3, \infty)$$